# Keep type-checking information across a variable boundary, when function signatures are handled internally

Tags: c, generics, macros, c17

**I am required to use C17 for this problem.**

I'm trying to design a coroutine system in standard C. This means no `ucontext` (as it's not standard) and no `longjmp` (as according to the standard downwards jumps are UB). I want this system to also be multithread compatible, which means I have to not destroy stack variables that are depended on by spawned fibers (more about this in the code example).

Here's a small example of what I would expect an example test program to look like. (This specific program is meant to test that the runtime system does not deadlock in the case that two fibers that would deadlock if executed sequentially are spawned concurrently.)

```c
static yield_t countdown_await(runtime_t* rt, size_t entrypoint) {
    RUNTIME_ARGUMENTS(rt, countdownlatch_t*, cdl);
    switch(entrypoint) {
        case 0: goto START;
        case 1: goto POST_AWAIT;
    }

    START:
        countdownlatch_countdown(rt);
        return COUNTDOWNLATCH_YIELD_AWAIT(rt, cdl, 1);
    POST_AWAIT:
        return YIELD_RETURN(rt);
}

static yield_t test_single_thread_concurrency(runtime_t* rt, size_t entrypoint) {
    RUNTIME_ARGUMENTS(rt, int, argc, char**, argv);
    RUNTIME_LOCAL(rt, countdownlatch_t*, cdl);
    RUNTIME_LOCAL(rt, fiber_t*, a);
    RUNTIME_LOCAL(rt, fiber_t*, b);
    switch(entrypoint) {
        case 0: goto START;
        case 1: goto POST_JOIN_A;
        case 2: goto POST_JOIN_B;
    }

    START:
        *cdl = countdownlatch_new(rt, 2);
        *a = RUNTIME_START(rt, countdown_await, *cdl);
        *b = RUNTIME_START(rt, countdown_await, *cdl);

        return RUNTIME_YIELD_JOIN(rt, *a, 1);
    POST_JOIN_A:
        return RUNTIME_YIELD_JOIN(rt, *b, 2);

    POST_JOIN_B:
        return YIELD_RETURN(rt, 0); // exit code
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    return RUNTIME_MAIN(test_single_thread_concurrency, argc, argv);
}
```

I face the following problems with this syntax and implementation:

- `RUNTIME_MAIN` does not have a mechanism to check that `test_single_thread_concurrency` accepts arguments `int argc` and `char** argv`
- `RUNTIME_MAIN` does not have a mechanism to check that `test_single_thread_concurrency` returns an `int` exit code
- `RUNTIME_YIELD_JOIN` does not have a mechanism to check that `a` and `b` are `void`-resulting fibers
- `RUNTIME_START` does not have a mechanism to check `countdown_await`'s arguments or its return type

Which means, in order to avoid UB, I've put a *large* mental burden on the programmer to remember the arguments and return types of each function, and refactoring tools no longer work. (Most of these macros would be implemented via various calls with `sizeof`s inside and casting to `void*` or `void (*)(void)`.)

I'm fine with introducing a ton of macros that completely change how code is written in order to accomplish this. I just want to make sure it is impossible (or at the very least, *really* difficult) to write code that includes type mismatches, while retaining the ability to

- call a coroutine function on the current fiber
- start a new fiber via a coroutine function, with arguments passed to this fiber able to point to data on the current stack (originally, I envisioned this to be handled by the `runtime_t` creating reference-counted stacks that link to each-other)
- join a fiber and obtain its result

I know of the existence of `_Generic`, but if it can be used to solve this problem, I have so far been unable to figure out the solution.

I am *required* to use C17 for this project (or I would have another language, such as ATS2, generate C code from a more strongly-typed language).

Comment: So is your goal to implement a `RUNTIME_ARGUMENTS` macro that unpacks `runtime_t* rt` into the appropriate arguments, but also throws a compile-time error if an attempt is made to invoke the function with a `runtime_t* rt` containing incorrect arguments?

Comment: Specifically, I want a compile time error to be thrown at `RUNTIME_START` if the supplied arguments do not conform to whatever function is being called there. I'm happy to be forced to add whatever information I need to the function declaration to achieve that: but duplicating the information to the caller defeats the point.

Comment: The structure of your `switch` statements with the different cases all using `goto` to jump to a label outside the `switch` is very peculiar.  You also don't cover the `default` or "none of the above" option explicitly and therefore fall through to the first label.  You should put the action code in the `switch` and decide what to do about the `default` case.

Comment: Not shown here, this pattern supports when a `switch` is nested. For example, I might have two `goto` points within a while loop that are both yields (such as yielding on a blocking read and then yielding on a blocking write of that data to somewhere else). Within that behavior I might have a `switch`, wherein the `case`s would conflict, so a `goto` chunk at the start is a more universal solution. See also the warning about switch/case in https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/coroutine.h

Comment: Regarding `default`, if a coroutine function is called with an `entrypoint` that is neither `0` nor a value previously returned by a yield, that is considered UB. So I'm fine with lacking a `default` case.